# How to pass DateTime value in url into ASP.Net Core MVC Controller from Postman

Tags: datetime, asp.net-core-mvc, postman

I am trying to test an endpoint that takes two DateTimes as parameters by sending in requests via Postman. Here is the Controller method:

```
[HttpGet("metrics/user/{ownerId}/{startDate}/{endDate}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserCompletionRate(int ownerId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    //Check if user exists
    var userExists = await unitOfWork.userAccountRepository
            .UserAccountExists(ownerId);
    //User doesn't exist
    if (!userExists) return NotFound("Couldn't find user.");
    //User exists
    Double completionRate = await unitOfWork.completionLogEntryRepository.GetUserCompletionRate(ownerId, startDate, endDate);
    return Ok(completionRate);
}
```

I've tried sending them in like this:

`http://.../api/metrics/user/2/2018-7-23T00:00:00/2018-7-24T10:24:00`

I then tried removing the parameters from the route and send it in like this:
`http://.../api/metrics/user?ownerId=2&startDate=2018-7-23T00:00:00&endDate=2018-7-24T10:24:00`

but nothing is working. I also tried declaring the dates in the route as `{startDate:datetime}` and nothing. How do I send in a DateTime object from Postman. I keep getting 404 Not Found errors.

Comment: As a starting point, I'd be inclined to try your second option, and declare them as strings, just to make sure you're getting what you expect.  Once you're actually getting values, you can either just parse the strings to date time objects, or continue to figure out how to get them straight as dateTime objects.

Comment: Could you share us your full controller code? If it is in `MVC Controller`, did you add any `Route` in the Controller? For this error, it is related with the URL and router, there is no problem in `DateTime`. Try request URL like `http://.../metrics/user/2/2018-7-23T00:00:00/2018-7-24T10:24:00`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two working demo for **MVC Controller** and **API Controller**.

MVC Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet("metrics/user/{ownerId}/{startDate}/{endDate}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserCompletionRate(int ownerId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        return Ok("Hello");
    }
```

Request:https://localhost:44393/metrics/user/2/2018-7-23T00:00:00/2018-7-24T10:24:00

API Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("metrics/user/{ownerId}/{startDate}/{endDate}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserCompletionRate(int ownerId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        return Ok("Hello");
    }
```

Request:https://localhost:44393/api/values/metrics/user/2/2018-7-23T00:00:00/2018-7-24T10:24:00